# Realizar un LEFT JOIN en Django

Tags: django

Soy algo nuevo en Python y Django y necesito hacer un LEFT JOIN con `raw` ya que no logro utilizar hacer funcionar el ORM con filtros relacionales. Al ejecutar el código me lanza un error `FieldDoesNotExist` con la descripción `Raw query must include the primary key.` Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida y super agradecida.

Mi models.py:

```
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_empresa = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    porcentaje = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    adicional = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    usuario_q = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'categorias'

class Zonas(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_empresa = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    observaciones = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    fecultmov = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    borra = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    usuario_q = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'zonas'

class Tipodocu(models.Model):
    sql_rowid = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True, null=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tipodocu'

class TiposContribuyentes(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    codigo = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    discrimina_iva = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tipos_contribuyentes'

class TiposDocumentos(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    codigo = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tipos_documentos'

class Provincias(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    codigo = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True, null=True)
    codigo_afip = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    usuario_q = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'provincias'

class Localidades(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_empresa = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    codigo = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    usuario_q = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'localidades'

class Clientes(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_empresa = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    id_categoria = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    id_zona = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    id_cuenta_contable = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    id_localidad = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    id_provincia = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    id_contribuyente = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    id_documento = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    cuit = models.CharField(max_length=13, blank=True, null=True)
    dgr = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    fecultmov = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    fecultfac = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    fecultfat = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    encargado = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    observaciones = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    aniversario = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    ctacte = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    montomax = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    d_atraso = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    agente = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    percepcion = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    factura_credito = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    monto_fcredito = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    borra = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    usuario_q = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'clientes'
```

Mi views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from clientes.models import Clientes

def clientes(request):
    clientes = Clientes.objects.raw('''SELECT 1 id, m.nombre ,m.direccion ,m.telefono ,m.cuit ,l.nombre ,p.nombre ,z.nombre ,c.nombre ,t.nombre FROM `clientes` AS m
                                    LEFT JOIN `localidades` AS l ON l.id=m.id_localidad
                                    LEFT JOIN `provincias` AS p ON p.id=m.id_provincia
                                    LEFT JOIN `categorias` AS c ON c.id=m.id_categoria
                                    LEFT JOIN `zonas` AS z ON z.id=m.id_zona
                                    LEFT JOIN `tipos_contribuyentes` AS t ON t.id=m.id_contribuyente
                                    WHERE m.id_empresa=1 and m.borra=0 ORDER BY m.nombre;''')
    return render(request, "clientes.html", {"clientes": clientes})
```

Desde ya gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: ¿Qué intentas obtener y no consigues con el ORM y las relaciones? Si defines en los modelos `campo = models.ForeignKey(Modelo-con-que-se-relaciona, on_delete=models.CASCADE o models.PROTECT), se forman las relaciones y es muy simple obtener los datos relacionados.

Comment: Por ejemplo, la relación entre cliente y provincia sería `provincia=models.ForeignKey(Provincia, on_delete.PROTECT, blank=True)` y en la plantilla para la vista pondrías {{ cliente.provincia.nombre }} (Por cierto, los nombres de los modelos mejor en singular)

Comment: Soy consciente de las foreign keys pero la tabla de datos esta mal formulada y el campo "nombre" contiene valores repetidos, y por lo que leí las foreign keys necesitan valores únicos para funcionar. Lo que a mi me gustaría lograr es mostrar la tabla de clientes para visualizar los datos al usuario.

Comment: Las ForeignKeys relacionan siempre por el objeto, e internamente las tablas lo harán a nivel del campo `id` que el ORM de Django crea aún si no lo has especificado. Las relaciones no son nunca por campos aleatorios ;)

Comment: Hola Sokkian, soy consciente de ello y las foreign keys apuntan directamente al campo id a menos que lo especifiques, probe especificarlo con to_field pero aun asi no dio resultado, y si lees mi comentario de arriba, las foreign keys no funcionan con valores que estén repetidos. Si tenés alguna idea de como lo puedo hacer te agradecería mucho